# Correspondence between two sets of meshes

Tags: mesh, vertices

I've stumbled across a problem that seems rather easy but couldn't found a satisfactory answer. What I want to do is get some sort of (weighted) correspondence, constraint, parent-child functionality ... between two sets of meshes such that if a vertex or face of one mesh is transformed, the related vertex / face of the other mesh transforms accordingly.
What I found was constraints relating the transformation of entire objects but not single vertex points / meshes.
Thank you all!

Comment: You can hook the meshes vertices with, say, some empties, and add constraints between them.

Comment: It seems like this could work however for a complex mesh like mine it sure is a lot of work to get the empties right. On top of that, setting "Copy Transform" constraints between them just moves them to the same location for whatever reason. What constraint did you have in mind?

Comment: Simply parenting the empties? As, if I understand what you want, it is to translate the same way? If you use a modifier for the hook (not the operation), maybe you can obtain the "weighted" effect you want using strength or vertex group.

Comment: translate, rotate, scale, move vertex position inside the mesh.. all that functionality would be required. What I've tried with the hook (parenting, adding constraints..) did not yield a good result :(